# Genarar listas java

Tags: java

Buenas estoy comenzando a utilizar listas en java y no sé muy bien como podría generar dos listas con 20 números aleatorios y mostrarlos por pantalla.

¿Para mostrarlos debería hacer un bucle for para que me lo imprima en cada iteración?  ¿podría imprimirse de una vez?

Tengo una clase para generar los números aleatorios, pero no sé como heredaría el main esa clase.

Main

```
    import java.util.*;
public class Ejercicio {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Vecino> lista_a = new ArrayList<Vecino>();
        List<Vecino> lista_b = new ArrayList<Vecino>();
    }
}
```

(No sé si estarían bien declaradas)
Utilizo import java.util.Random para generar los números aleatorios, no sabría como poner 20 de esos números en cada una de esas dos listas. Y otra duda sería, a la hora de comparar el contenido de cada una de las dos listas, por ejemplo si en la lista a en la posicion 0 tiene un valor 8623412 y en la lista b en la posicion 0 tiene un valor 8199842, ¿cómo podría hacer un recorrido de esos dos valores para saber si el ultimo digito son iguales (en este caso el ultimo digito de ambos es un 2)? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿El objeto Vecino tiene una propiedad en la cual almacenaras los numeros aleatorios? @Samuel

Comment: Podrías subir tu clase de  números aleatorios?

Answer (score 0):

1. Generar dos listas con 20 números aleatorios y mostrarlos por pantalla.
2. Usar aleatorios desde una clase, (no me parece necesario) pero te muestro.
3. Comparar los números de cada lista en orden para verificar si el ultimo dígito es igual.

> 1.Generar dos listas con 20 números aleatorios y mostrarlos por pantalla.
>
> Todo el código es escrito en el main salvo la clase Aleatorio de ejemplo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //Utilizo ArrayList<Integer> porque lo que hay dentro son números
   //No sé por qué en tu código tenes vecinos.
   ArrayList<Integer> listaAleatoria1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Integer> listaAleatoria2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

> 2. Usar aleatorios desde una clase, (no me parece necesario) pero te muestro.

```
 //Inicializo la clase Aleatorio con nombre ale.
 Aleatorio ale = new Aleatorio();
 //cargo las dos listas con 20 números aleatorios.
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
      //aca uso un metodo de la clase main
      listaAleatoria1.add(azar());
      //aca uso la clase Aleatorio 
      listaAleatoria2.add(ale.genAleatorioHasta(50));
   }
```

> 3. Comparar los números de cada lista en orden para verificar si el ultimo dígito es igual.

```
   //Recorro y comparo con un método de la clase main.
   for(int i=0;i<listaAleatoria1.size();i++) {
       int l1=listaAleatoria1.get(i);
       int l2=listaAleatoria2.get(i);
       System.out.println( i+"- L1 "+l1+" L2 "+l2+ "=" +ultimoDig(l1,l2));
   }

 //Método comparador.
   private static boolean ultimoDig(int num1,int num2) {
     //es igual el ultimo digito de cada numero?
     boolean res = false;
     //numero % (mod(resto de dividir por)) 10 te selecciona el ultimo digito
     res = (Math.abs(num1) % 10) ==(num2 % 10);
         
     return res;
 }
 //Método para un número al azar, alternativa a la Clase
 private static int azar() {
     Random r1 = new Random();
     long semilla = r1.nextLong();
     r1.setSeed(semilla);
     return r1.nextInt();
 }
```

> Clase modelo Aleatorio.

```
 import java.util.Random;

 public class Aleatorio {

 public Aleatorio() {
    
 }
 public int genAleatorioHasta(int hasta) {
    Random ram= new Random();
    long semilla = ram.nextLong();
    ram.setSeed(semilla);
    int res = ram.nextInt(hasta);
    return res;
 }

}
```

Comment: Tene en cuenta que segun la documentacion, Random es una funcion pseudoaleatoria. Crear un nuevo random en cada vuelta no asegura que no seleccionara exactamente el mismo numero todas las veces. En general a random se le debe pasar una semilla.

Comment: Sugerís que le ponga una semilla al azar cada vez que pido un random?